# unable to import pandas in jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, import, anaconda, jupyter

When I import pandas in jupyter library the following is generated.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-f869c0f42cc0> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
      3 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     24 
     25 try:
---> 26     from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,
     27                              lib as _lib,
     28                              tslib as _tslib)

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in init pandas._libs.hashtable()

AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.hashtable.HashTable' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Can you help me in figuring out the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use pd at the place of pandas in your code. If you still get error, then write your code also in the question.